# having trouble with implementing producer consumer problem

Tags: c, multithreading, producer-consumer, consumer

I am trying to implement the consumer producer problem, butI am running in a problem, I think I get stuck in an infinite loop, but I have no idea where.

Here is my code:

```
#define MAX_NUM 30 // borne sup des valeurs du tableau
#include <pthread.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100 // taille maximale du tableau
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int tab [MAX_SIZE];
int size_tab ;
int Veut_entrer[2];
int Tour=0;
//1 equals to true and 0 equals to false
typedef unsigned int uint; //on declare le type variable globale
 
void* lock(int index)
{
Veut_entrer[Tour]=1;
Tour=1-index;
while(Veut_entrer[1-index]==1 && Tour==1-index)
        {
            //on attend 
        }
 
 }
 
 void unlock(Tour)
 {
    Veut_entrer[Tour]=0;
    
 }
 void * produce ( int index ) {
    uint count = 0;
    while ( count < 5) {
 debut section critique
    lock(Tour);
    //printf("Oui ou non %d  et %d" ,Veut_entrer[index],Tour);
    tab [size_tab ++] = rand() % MAX_NUM ;
    printf ("produce : %d\n", tab[size_tab-1]);
 fin section critique
    unlock(Tour);
    //printf("hein");
    count ++;
    //printf("ici");
    return (NULL);}
                            }
 int compare ( const void* a , const void* b ) {
    int const* pa = a ;
    int const* pb = b ;
    return (*pb - *pa );
 }
 
 void* consume ( int index ) {
    uint count = 0;
    printf("stuck");
 
 
    //printf("Oui ou non %d " ,Veut_entrer[0]);
    while ( count != 5) {
 if ( count < size_tab ) {
 printf("stuck");
 debut section critique
 lock(index);
     //printf("Oui ou non %d  et %d" ,Veut_entrer[index],Tour);
 qsort(tab ,MAX_SIZE / sizeof(int) ,sizeof(int) ,compare);//algortiheme qui permet de trier le tableau tant que la taille du tableau est inférieur a 5=count
 printf("consume : sort [%d elements] =>" ,size_tab);
 for(uint i = 0; i < size_tab ; i ++)
 printf ( " %d" , tab[i]);
    printf ( "\n" );
    count = size_tab ;
 fin section critique
    unlock(index);
                                }
                        }
     
    return(NULL);                       }
 
 
 int init()
 {
    Veut_entrer[0]=0;
    Veut_entrer[1]=0;   
 }
 int main (){
    int index_prod=0;
    int index_cons=1;
    pthread_t thread1 ;
    pthread_t thread2 ;
 char* m1 = " mon parametre " ;
 char* m2="truc";
    //printf("ici erreur");
    init();
    //printf("Oui ou non %d " ,Veut_entrer[0]);
    //produce(index);
    //consume(index);
    //printf("erreu");
    pthread_create (&thread1 , NULL ,produce(index_prod),( void *) m1);// The pthread_create() function starts a new thread in the calling process.
    //printf("erreur");
    //pthread_join (thread1 ,NULL );//The pthread_join() function shall suspend execution of the calling thread until the target thread terminates,
    printf("herr");
    pthread_create (&thread2,NULL,consume(index_cons),( void *) m2);
    //pthread_join(thread2,NULL);
    //pthread_join (thread1 ,NULL );
    return 0;
 }
```

The expected output is:

```
produce : 13
 consume : sort [1 elements ] = > 13
 produce : 16
 consume : sort [2 elements ] = > 16 13
 produce : 27
 consume : sort [3 elements ] = > 27 16 13
 produce : 25
 consume : sort [4 elements ] = > 27 25 16 13
 produce : 23
 consume : sort [5 elements ] = > 27 25 23 16 13
```

So each time I produce, meaning tab has at lease 1 element, I consume.

Comment: _"I think I get stuck in an infinite loop"_ - isn't that the whole idea? You'll _want_ an infinite-loop to mediate between the producer and the consumer...

Comment: Please format your code so we can read it. Right now the indentation is unreadably inconsistent.

Comment: @Dai when i say an infinte loop i mean by that my computer is heating up and it's not working as intended

Comment: Use your step-through debugger then.

Comment: @Dai never heard of that but are my lock and unlock function correct?

Comment: ...you've never heard of step-through debugger? GDB? WinDbg? KD? LLDB? Step-Into/Step-Out/Step-Over? ...how are you learning C without adequate tooling? Every entry-level IDE I see today has a step-through debugger built-in to it, even Arduino IDE supports it now too.

Comment: You are not using any synchronization (mutex, semaphore) to protect access to your shared variables.  So no, your `lock()` and `unlock()` functions *are not* correct.

Comment: @Dai ah i see i know GDB,but i only used it to learn some X86assembly

Comment: @JohnBollinger but isn't the mutex in this lock and unlock which are implemented according to Peterson and Dekker algorithm?

Comment: @TheEndOfTheCycle, your `lock()` and `unlock()` functions don't exactly match the textbook pseudocode for Peterson's and Dekker's algorithm, but I'm not sure they are incorrect in that sense.  The sense in which they are definitely incorrect is that the algorithm depends on a much stronger memory model than pthreads promises or typical systems with multiple execution units provide.  To account for that, you need at minimum to make the variables on which your `lock()` and `unlock()` rely atomic.

Comment: @JohnBollinger should i use semaphores then to try to understand the problem better?

Comment: It depends on your objectives, @TheEndOfTheCycle.  If they include studying Dekker's algorithm then using atomic variables in your implementation seems like the most natural way to proceed.  But if Dekker's is incidental to you, then you should be looking at approaches built around Pthreads condition variables, which are used together with (Pthreads) mutexes.  This combination is the all-purpose mechanism for coordinating actions of multiple threads, and producer / consumer is one of the standard problems used for teaching it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger so if i understand correctly the problem is the lack of mutuel exclusion provided by the mutex when i access the variable Tour and Count?

Comment: @TheEndOfTheCycle Put simply, your spinlock in `lock()` is not actually a real, working, mutex lock.

Comment: Computer architectures today are more sophisticated and subtle than the computers for which Dekker's algorithm, Peterson's algorithm, Lamport's "Bakery algorithm," etc. were designed. Modern computers do not always perform store and fetch operations to memory in the exact order that the program specifies, and those old algorithms depend very much on _exact_ memory ordering. In order for them to work on modern hardware, they must be modified by the addition of platform-specific [memory barrier instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) in appropriate places.

Comment: @TheEndOfTheCycle, when I say that Dekker's relies on a "stronger memory model", I mean approximately that it depends on (1) each thread's writes to `Veut_entre` and `Tour` to be performed as atomic units that are immediately visible to the other thread, (2) that each thread's reads and writes of *all* shared variables not be reordered with respect to its reads and writes of `Veut_entre` and `Tour`, and [...]

Comment: [...] (3) that one thread, having observed a write **W** to `Veut_entre` or `Tour` by the other, should also be able to observe all the other's writes to any shared variables that occurred before **W**.  POSIX does not ensure any of those in your code. The mutual exclusion behavior of your `lock` and `unlock` functions is therefore not reliable, but also, the spinlock in your `lock` function is probably where your program is getting stuck.  Furthermore, you need the memory semantics described for even for working mutual exclusion to ensure the desired behavior for the rest of the program.